# Response.Redirect to different domain from asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

in asp.net MVC controller in action I want to redirect URL but it does now work

```
     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public ActionResult SearchResults()
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://hybridsoftware.net/b/error.htm?Error=test", true);
.....
```

I tried also false or only url but it does not work

Also I tried this

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public ActionResult SearchResults()
        {

            return new RedirectResult("https://hybridsoftware.net/b/error.htm?Error=test");
}
```

No error but this now work,it does not redirect to that page : https://hybridsoftware.net/b/error.htm?Error=test

I am doing ajax call to SearchResults and in that action result I want to rediret to this page https://hybridsoftware.net/b/error.htm?Error=test in asp.net mvc controller ActionResult

Answer (score 0):

Respone.Redirect can be used for WebForms (class ASP.NET). For an MVC controller, you'll want to return a `RedirectResult` instance.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public ActionResult SearchResults()
{
    return new RedirectResult("https://hybridsoftware.net/b/error.htm?Error=test");
}
```

Given the update information about the AJAX call to this controller action, you'll need to update whatever is making the call on the client side to respect the returned status code and set `window.location` to the URI returned.

Comment: [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public ActionResult SearchResults()
        {

            return new RedirectResult("https://hybridsoftware.net/b/error.htm?Error=test");
}

Comment: this does not give error but does not work,it does not redirect to hybridsoftware.net/b....

Comment: @user1688401 then you'll need to update your javascript to redirect the user based on the response of the controller action.